# SQL String: Sum of maximum of distinct values (group by)

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Assume the following table:

```
ID     COMPANY     SUBSIDIARY     NR_LIVES     INSURANCE_LINE     FACTOR_CALC
1      COMPANY_X   SUB_1          860          LIFE               YES
2      COMPANY_X   SUB_1          860          DISABILITY         YES
3      COMPANY_X   SUB_1          860          MEDICAL            YES 
4      COMPANY_X   SUB_2          46           LIFE               YES
5      COMPANY_X   SUB_2          689          MEDICAL            YES
6      COMPANY_X   SUB_3          852          LIFE               YES
```

I need an SQL string that returns to me the value 2401. 
This is done by making the sum of the highest NR_Of_Lives per subsidiary where FACTOR_CALC = Yes. 
I probably would know how to do it loading everything in a recordset and then using VBA, but I would appreciate it if it were possible in one SQL command.

UPDATE: 
The current query:

```
sSQL_Select = "SELECT SUM(NR_LIVES) FROM (SELECT SUBSIDIARY, MAX(NR_LIVES) FROM T_WILMA WHERE PARENT=" & lParent & " AND ACC_YEAR=" & lAcc_Year & _
                " AND FACTOR_CALCULATION=TRUE GROUP BY SUBSIDIARY);"
```

throws an error: Too few parameters, expected 1. 
The subquery on its own works as expected. 
Thanks to replies so far, but I haven't succeeded to make it work so far.

Comment: When you get the "too few parameters" error, paste your SELECT statement into SQL View of a new query in the query designer, then try to run it.  Access will display a dialog window titled "Enter Parameter Value" with the name of the (first) missing parameter as the first line below the dialog title.  So what does Access think is a missing parameter?

Comment: I meant you should `Debug.Print sSQL_Select` and test that statement in the query designer.

Comment: It is the NR_LIVES parameter. Very strange! (Well, I call it EMPLOYEES_COVERED now instead, but it is the same principle. I made a copy-paste so there are no typos. Moreover, in the subquery, I use the same field name, and there it works without error(?)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest you include some aliasing to see whether that helps unconfuse the db engine.

```
sSQL_Select = "SELECT SUM(sub.MaxOfNR_LIVES) AS NR_LIVES" & vbcrlf & _
    "FROM (" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT SUBSIDIARY, MAX(NR_LIVES) AS MaxOfNR_LIVES" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM T_WILMA WHERE PARENT=" & lParent & _
    " AND ACC_YEAR=" & lAcc_Year & _
    " AND FACTOR_CALCULATION=TRUE GROUP BY SUBSIDIARY) AS sub;"
Debug.Print sSQL_Select
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure.  In the subq you originally had `MAX(NR_LIVES)` without an alias.  Then, in the parent query, you tried to `SUM(NR_LIVES)` which perhaps made the db engine wonder "where the heck is this NR_LIVES thing he's asking for ... can't find it in the data source (the subq), so must be a parameter".

Comment: Could be... I expected that the subquery would return a table with field name NR_LIVES (containing records with max values only)... strange that the parent query cannot find back the field then, but apparently it doesn't work this way. I'll keep this in mind and will use more aliases in the future.

Comment: Try the subquery by itself as a new query in the query designer.  If you don't assign an alias to MAX(NR_LIVES), when you run the query Access will supply one ... like Expr1000.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the maximum per subsidiary in a subquery.  The outer query can then sum the maximums.

```
select  sum(MaxLives)
from    (
        select  company
        ,       subsidiary
        ,       max(nr_lives) as MaxLives
        from    YourTable
        where   factor_calc = 'yes'
        group by
                company
        ,       subsidiary
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: Well, I've got something similar now:sSQL_Select = "SELECT SUM(MAX(EMPLOYEES COVERED)) FROM T_WILMA WHERE PARENT=" & lParent & " AND ACC_YEAR=" & lAcc_Year & " AND FACTOR_CALCULATION=TRUE)GROUP BY SUBSIDIARY;" But I get an error saying: "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'sum(max(employees covered)) I'm not very experienced with advanced SQL stmts.

Comment: You can't nest aggregates like `sum(max(col1))`.  Have you tried the subquery approach from this answer?

Comment: Yes, thanks but I get an error "Too few parameters, Expected 1" now. When trying the subquery on its own, it seems fine...

Comment: @KimGysen check your field names, again

Comment: Yes, I don't see a mistake... the subquery works and I just placed "SELECT SUM(NR_LIVES) FROM " before, so it should work... I solved the problem now by just looping through the recordset of the subquery.

Comment: +1 You actually mentioned it; I didn't think that putting the alias explicitly would be that big a deal but it was.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(NR_LIVES) 
from(
SELECT SUBSIDIARY,MAX(NR_LIVES) as NR_LIVES
from <Table>
where  FACTOR_CALC='YES'
group by SUBSIDIARY)a
```

Comment: This would sum all nr_lives, instead of only the highest nr_lives per subsidiary

Comment: Hmm, the subquery on its own works properly, but with the sum I get an error "Too few parameters, Expected 1"...

Answer (score 0):

You need to let the system know which NR_LIVES it's trying to add up. On your table (and taking out the extra stuff in the `WHERE` that is not in your example, this returns 2401

```
SELECT Sum(MAXNR_LIVES) AS Expr1
FROM (SELECT SUBSIDIARY, MAX(NR_LIVES) AS MAXNR_LIVES FROM T_WILMA 
WHERE FACTOR_CALC=TRUE GROUP BY SUBSIDIARY);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found the answer I was looking for (see above).